# Jquery iterate table, having merged cells, rows and columns but skip first column

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am able to iterate all rows and columns but it does not work when table have merged cells.
It does not go through the merged row for all normal columns(not having any merged cells).

My script:

```
$('#test tr').each(function() {
   $(this).find('td').each(function(colIndex)   
    {
        if(colIndex > 1)
        {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });   
});
```

[A like example/test is available here:](http://jsfiddle.net/pMWAw/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#test tr').each(function() {



    var rowcount=0;
   $(this).find('td').each(function(colIndex)   
    {
        if(colIndex > 1)
        {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
      rowcount ++;
    }); 
  if(rowcount==2)
  {
     $(this).find('td').each(function(colIndex)   
    {
        if(colIndex == 1)
        {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }

    });
  }


});
```

Modify your jquery like this. This will do. http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/pMWAw/26/

Comment: The solution is hard-coded for 2 merged cells(rowspan=2) but it vary in real. there can be any number of merged cells in first column. How can we just skip the first column and start column iteration from 2nd column? so that we do not need to take care of how many cells are merged.

Comment: If row span changes then it affect next coloumn? Can't clearly get what you want

Comment: You have hardcode it to count 2 columns and then start looking the next row since the merged cell spans to 2 rows but the rowpan can be different for different cells and there can be any number of columns from 3 to n hence I would like it to keep dynamic. Please check the solution, I have updated to fiddle example.

Comment: I updated my fiddle is this you trying to say? Your fiddle isn't updated

Comment: Your solution work only when there are 2 columns after the first one. it will need to be changed to 3 if another column is added and will be needed so on for all new columns?

Comment: But still it only updates the last column but I need to change all columns besides first

Comment: Updated!! I earlier thought You need to update last column only.. But still  you need to know number of columns for this solution

Comment: although not perfect solution but I accept it as answer, as its very close to what I wanted. Thank you for quick replies and solution!

Comment: Yes :) There may be simple solution but it entertains to work with loop in jquery

Answer (score 1):

Can be simplified to one line - just use the `:last-child` selector

```
$('#test tr td:last-child').css('background-color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pMWAw/12/

Comment: There can be any number of columns to the right side of table hence I need to iterate all rows and all columns besides the first column (which has merged cells)